# Sci-fi series from the 70’s/80’s about a group of children from outer space living in America

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I thought it was called 'Children of Z' or 'Children of X' - but I have not found it. It was written by a woman, I believe.

Comment: _[Galactica 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactica_1980)_ (shudder)....

Answer (score 8):

Zenna Henderson's "The People" sequence, perhaps? It's not a perfect match but it fits the "written by a woman" and "aliens hiding among humanity" criteria. Psychic aliens, though that's not part of the original question. The timeframe is plausible, since they were originally published in the 1960s. No "Children of X" title, though, and not all the aliens are themselves children.

There's a [reasonable overview](https://reactormag.com/immigrants-in-an-alien-world-zenna-hendersons-the-people-no-different-flesh/) on the former Tor site.

At least one of them, "Gilead", was collected in an anthology titled ["Tomorrow's Children"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?51964).

Comment: Yes! That’s it!! Thank you!

Comment: @HeatherDaniel lucky guess on my part, then! You should be able to check a green checkmark by this answer to mark the answer as "accepted", which will show other users that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 7):

[Halfway Across the Galaxy and Turn Left](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/HalfwayAcrossTheGalaxyAndTurnLeft)

> Halfway Across the Galaxy and Turn Left is a children's novel by Robin Klein, which was turned into a 1994 television series.
>
> When X's father is caught cheating in the Zyrgonian lottery for the 27th time, the Zyrgonian government loses patience. When they send their officials after him, the head of the family, ten-year-old X herself, sees no choice but to flee as far away as possible. So she and her family go halfway across the galaxy, and turn left, taking shelter on an ignored and primitive planet called Earth. Though originally intending only to hide out on Earth until the government is overthrown again, eventually, they decide they prefer living on Earth.
>
> Followed by a literature sequel, Turn Right for Zyrgon, where the family and X's closest human friend, Jenny, are kidnapped back to Zyrgon to sort out some governmental issues involving their aunt. When Jenny gets mistaken for a goddess due to a reaction to Zyrgonian crystal cakes, things only get worse. Fortunately, they ultimately sort things out and choose to return to Earth.
>
> The television series mostly focuses on X's problems controlling her loopy family on an alien planet, while the government on her own planet relentlessly searches for them. X's desperate attempts for her family to fit in with Earth society leave her fighting an uphill battle,by

I found an episode on YouTube:

Answer (score 7):

Disney's [*Witch Mountain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Mountain_(franchise)) series ([based on eponymous novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain) by [Alexander Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Key), who was not a woman), which began in the 1970s, started with [*Escape to Witch Mountain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_(1975_film)) and is about "a group of children" gifted with various psionic abilities "from outer space living in America."